# Custom DataBase in Apache Pulsar Manager

Tags: postgresql, apache-pulsar

I've Apache Pulsar configured on IBM Cloud Kubernetes Cluster. It includes Pulsar Manager too. I want to customize the database to use PostgreSQL for Pulsar Manager. I've replaced the database properties in `application.properties` file to use PostgreSQL. [Ref](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/administration-pulsar-manager/)

But When I see Pulsar manager UI, it still shows me old topics/namespaces etc. It seems it is not connecting to my standalone PostgreSQL. Looking for some help on the same.

Please see the logs from Pulsar Manager pod:

```
2021-10-21 09:22:10.333 UTC [25] LOG: listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2021-10-21 09:22:10.338 UTC [25] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-10-21 09:22:10.342 UTC [25] LOG: listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2021-10-21 09:22:10.361 UTC [26] LOG: database system was shut down at 2021-10-21 09:22:10 UTC
2021-10-21 09:22:10.366 UTC [25] LOG: database system is ready to accept connections
```

Please help me on the same. Many Thanks!

I've done changes in application.properties file as below:
`env: - name: PULSAR_CLUSTER value: pulsar - name: USERNAME valueFrom: secretKeyRef: name: pulsar-pulsar-manager-secret key: PULSAR_MANAGER_ADMIN_USER - name: PASSWORD valueFrom: secretKeyRef: name: pulsar-pulsar-manager-secret key: PULSAR_MANAGER_ADMIN_PASSWORD - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME valueFrom: configMapKeyRef: name: pulsar-pg-config key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL valueFrom: configMapKeyRef: name: pulsar-pg-config key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME valueFrom: configMapKeyRef: name: pulsar-pg-config key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD valueFrom: configMapKeyRef: name: pulsar-pg-config key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD`

I've used these values in Pulsar Manager's deployment file as below:

```
name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME
```

valueFrom:
configMapKeyRef:
name: pulsar-pg-config
key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME

- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
  valueFrom:
  configMapKeyRef:
  name: pulsar-pg-config
  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL

Comment: Please show your properties file

Comment: apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: pulsar-pg-config
data:
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: org.postgresql.Driver
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://2d35e253-c12d-4caf-a020-1240105f0996.bm49h38l0bihsg5ne8d0.databases.appdomain.cloud:32020/pulsar_manager
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: admin
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: password

Comment: I've used these values in Pulsar Manager's deployment file as below: - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pulsar-pg-config
                  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pulsar-pg-config
                  key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL

Comment: Please edit your question rather than put code in the comments